# JQuery Javascript undefined paradox

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

Could someone please explain why the alert is triggered and states that the variable is undefined, when the `if` test says that it is defined?

```
var some_var;
if(typeof some_var !== undefined){
    alert(some_var);   
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8bx2fo0/)

Comment: `typeof some_var !== 'undefined'` as typeof something gives a string value

Comment: Why do you need `typeof` for that? Why not `some_var !== undefined`?

Comment: @MinusFour, that's what I used in the first place, but the result was not as expected. So I then used `typeof`. I have used `undefined` so many times before, but @Tushar's explanation of strict inequality taught me a valuable lesson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof` always returns string.

As you're using strict inequality, the condition evaluates to `true`.

You can either

1. use `undefined` as string
2. use `!=` for inequality

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/z8bx2fo0/1/)

```js
var some_var;
if (typeof some_var !== 'undefined') {
  alert(some_var);
}
```

As suggested by @MinusFour, you can use

```
if (some_var !== undefined) {
```

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation.